Grid Having issues with a div sitting on top of a div with opacity
I have a Codepen here.
As the title says I’m out of solutions to understand how to get a div that's sitting on top of a div with opacity to show up. This is just a little page of book lists. I like to code HTML but I’m not very good at it. :)
The issue would appear to be simple but I've asked others for help and none of us can solve it. I hesitate to load the whole page here (it’s a lot). Lastly, I had a friend code the tabs for me so trust me I don’t understand any of the SVG! He’s currently on a beach drinking margaritas or I’d ask him
Okay I tried doing this and it didn’t work:


.opaq {
    padding: 4.5rem 0 0 0;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255 / .6);
    opacity: 0.6;
}
.solid {
    padding: 4.5rem;
    margin: 0 4.5rem 4.5rem 4.5rem;
    background-color: white;
}
.main {
    padding: 4.5rem;
    font-style: normal;
    text-align: left;
    color: black;
    font-family: 'solway', serif;
    font-size: 2.75rem;
    line-height: 1.08;
    font-weight: bold;
}
<div class="content-area">
<!-- All content goes in here including tables and will sit on top of the image. -->

<div class="tile">
<div class="opaq">
<div class="solid">
<div class="leadb">
Eight<br>
History Mystery<br>
Writers</div>
<div class="leadc">
by semicodin
</div>




opacity is always rendered last and as such will always effect all child elements and can't be countered.

Is that a long way of saying I can’t have the background >tile in this page? Because it’s currently eliminated with Tim’s fix below. Oh this would be disappointing to say the least. It ruins the design.

Tim's fix does not fix the opacity issue. He simply removed opacity to not have the issue in the first place. It was not a long saying that it can't be done. It was a short saying why it can't be done with opacity.

I don’t understand your response tacoshy I’m sorry. I just want to have the 3 “layers” I described in my post below. I have 2 of them now (the opaque and the solid); I am missing the 3rd (the background tile).

what are you trying to do ? a white background in the middle and background mixed a bit with white around it ? what is your expected result ? is it alike https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/MWdNzMp

Change this

.opaq {
    padding: 4.5rem 0 0rem 0;

to this
.opaq {
    padding: 4.5rem 0 .25rem 0;

to complete the padding on the .opaq layer at the bottom, giving the design a polished off look.

The issue is due to an incorrect declaration.
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255 / .6);
opacity: 0.6;

Replace the forward slash with a comma and remove the opacity declaration
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255, .6);

Also see I do not want to inherit the child opacity from the parent in CSS

Thank you Tim but it wipes out my background tile! There are three “layers” to this: the background tile, the opaque layer, and the white layer where the content lives. How can we get the paisley tile back? Thank you and thank you also for that link.

Just one closing comment. There is a fix I put in the Codepen restoring the tile background that Tim’s fix wiped out. So you see there are not one but TWO solutions to this and you’ll find them both in my Codepen. Peace.

Tim had half of the solution. The other half was to add
padding: 4.5rem;

to the style .tile to make the tiling background visible. I don’t know how to split the award for the solution between us so I’m doing it here.
